# How to prevent a lua script from failing when a `require` fails to find the script required?

Tags: lua

Is it possible to prevent a lua script from failing when a `require` fails to find the script required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Lua errors are handled by [`pcall`](http://www.lua.org/pil/8.4.html) function. You could wrap `require` with it:

```
local requireAllDependenciesCallback = function()
    testModul = require 'test';
    -- Other requires.
end;

if pcall(requireAllDependenciesCallback) then
    print('included');
else
    print('failed');
end
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/mRSMkv)

**Note:** `pcall` is really expensive and should not be actively used. Make sure, you *really* need to mute `require` fails.

Comment: Thanks PLB, that works. When you say it shouldn't be actively used, is that purely from a performance perspective or are there other issues?

Comment: @MarkNuttall-Smith Performance only. If you decide to use `pcall` for this. I'd suggest creating some function that will be handling all requires to avoid too much `pcall`s. E.g.: `local requireFiles = function() -- requires here. end;` and pass it to `pcall`.

Comment: Performance is not a concern for me here actually, because it's just during start up of the app that I will be doing this. I wanted to be able to either find dependencies in a user specific directory, or a shared location. Thanks again.

Answer (score 10):

This is basic usage

```
if pcall(require, 'test') then
    -- done but ...
    -- In lua 5.2 you can not access to loaded module.
else
    -- not found
end
```

But since Lua 5.2 it is deprecated set global variables when load library you should use returned value from require.
And using only pcall you need :

```
local ok, mod = pcall(require, "test")
-- `mod` has returned value or error 
-- so you can not just test `if mod then` 
if not ok then mod = nil end
-- now you can test mod
if mod then
  -- done
end
```

I like this function

```
local function prequire(m) 
  local ok, err = pcall(require, m) 
  if not ok then return nil, err end
  return err
end

-- usage
local mod = prequire("test")
if mod then 
  -- done
end
```

Comment: The last one is really _sweet_. Language itself should be having something like that. The thing I don't like is that `pcall` will be called on every `prerequire`.

Comment: I do not think this is big problem. cfunction `pcall` call cfunction `require`.

Comment: I would like to see this function in standard library too. Also as function that allows load one library from list (`bit = vrequire("bit32", "bit")`).

Comment: AFAIK Lua is open-source. I hope someone will add that and make pull request. If I was little bit free, I could play with it but unfortunately business stuff is more important. :(

Comment: Lua is open source but development in close. Best way is write purpose on lua-l mail list. There no official open repository. In paste week there were Lua 5.3-work1 that add integers to Lua.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `pcall`, you add can your own loader at the end of the list of loaders and make it so that your loader never fails but instead returns a special value, such as a string. Then you can use require normally and just check its return value. (Loaders are now called searchers in 5.2.)

Comment: But this is influences to all modules. And this is may be big surprise that `require` return invalid value.